# Does Curtis end up killing someone when switching out his Misfits power?

Tags: misfits

In "Six", episode 6 of series 3 of *Misfits*, the one with Simon helping Rudy remember the night of a party and the group sitting around waiting for the new probation worker, Curtis finds himself unable to control his sex switching powers.

[image: Curtis comes to another realisation about his powers]

It's revealed that it's because he's/she's pregnant and that the further along, the less control he has of his powers. Toward the end he's stuck as a girl before making the deal with Seth to take away his powers. Doing so reverts him back to male Curtis.

Does this mean the fetus was killed/miscarried?

Or does the removal of the mother mean that there couldn't have been a child growing in the first place and no death takes place?

Answer (score 2):

I don't think it ought to be referred to as an abortion.  I've been thinking of it as a miscarriage, as essentially the fetus was no longer in an environment where it was nurtured and could grow.  It wasn't an abortion via any of the normal means, and that term has such a negative connotation.

To answer the underlying question, yes, that fetus is gone.  It's unclear what happened to it.  Either it is still in Curtis' abdomen, or it ceased to exist along with Curtis' uterus.

Comment: Right, guv, removed the "abortion" from the question, but not so much as to invalidate your answer